# Como aumentar a espessura de um text-shadow

Tags: css

É possível aumentar a espessura de um `text-shadow` ?

Olhem esse [**EXEMPLO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreBR/Q8dX9/) no JSFiddle

Simplesmente, é como se eu não tivesse colocado um `text-shadow`, fica invisível.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duas sugestões para resolver o problema:

- Utilizar um contraste melhor. A sombra branca se difunde no azul por trás e não fica muito perceptível;
- Usar **múltiplas sombras**. As sombras via CSS para texto são realmente pequenas, e quando você aumenta o raio do amaciamento, elas ficam tão tênues que fica cada vez mais difícil vê-las. Felizmente a sintaxe da sombra permite múltiplas sombras por elemento, bastando separar as sombras por vírgulas.

Experimenta usar:

```
text-shadow: 0 0 30px #FFF, 0 0 30px #FFF, 0 0 30px #FFF, 0 0 30px #FFF, 0 0 30px #FFF, 0 0 30px #FFF, 0 0 30px #FFF;
```

No seu Fiddle. Você também pode variar os *offsets* de cada sombra para obter efeitos interessantes ;)

Comment: Vou testar agora.

Comment: Quando se utiliza várias sombras ele fica sem resolução, meio borrado. Veja: http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreBR/Q8dX9/2/

Comment: Ajustando os offsets você consegue melhorar o efeito. Olha: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8dX9/3/ Para conseguir um efeito mais artístico, você pode também combinar cores próximas entre si.

Comment: Eu ajustei e ficou perfeito! eu utilizei `text-shadow: 0 0 15px #FFF, 0 0 30px #FFF, 0 0 40px #FFF, 0 0 40px #FFF, 0 0 50px #FFF;` Eu vou aumentando os pixeis, tipo 10, 20, 30. Assim ele vai desparecendo suavemente! Veja: http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreBR/Q8dX9/4/